# Link with colour and underline

Tags: color, links, underline

I am using the `hyperref` package to colour my urls in the text. I've tried adding an underline as well with the last two lines below for the `hypersetup`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=red,
    pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1},
    allbordercolors=red
}

\begin{document}

Go to \url{www.example.com} to check it out.

\end{document}
```

As an alternative to `allbordercolors` I have tried `urlbordercolor` specifically but with no success.

These extra lines make no difference - only colouring works, not underlining:

[image]

I do not see the difference from my scenario to example scenarios that I find online. Where is my mistake that prevents underlining of urls?

Comment: move `\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}}`  after \begin{document}.

Comment: BTW, \S solid, \U underline, \W width in pt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hyperref sets some option at \begin{document}. It works if you move the pdfborderstyle declaration:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=red,
    allbordercolors=red,
}

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}}
 Go to \url{www.example.com} to check it out. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use the new hyperref driver by loading the pdf management it works also in the preamble:

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=red,
    allbordercolors=red,
    pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}
}

\begin{document}
 Go to \url{www.example.com} to check it out. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also use `\AtBeginDocument{\def\@pdfborderstyle{/S/U/W 1}}`

Comment: Thank you, this works. Is there also a way to reduce the distance to the underline? It seems to overlap the text line underneath as it is now.